# Deploying metadata From Production to Developer Edition

Tags: metadata, deployment

I'm trying to learn the smooth of pushing the metadata from production to developer edition or any other sandbox.

I have installed MavensMate (MM) on my computer and I get the latest metadata from production and now I want to push that metadata to developer edition box, what is the best way to do so?

The one approach I have tried is this (its very painful)

1. Create a new project in MM using developer edition
2. Copy/Paste the production metadata in the developer edition and save the
   project.

Is there any better approach then this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging), add the components you want, and then do a normal upload and install process. The advantage of this approach is that the package manager automatically enforces that all required sub-components are placed into the package. For example, if you add an account page layout, the package manager will also automatically select all the custom buttons, the pages for any Visualforce pages linked to those buttons, and the controllers for those Visualforce pages. Note that not all dependencies can be automatically detected, so may still need to go through a few versions to get everything correctly packaged, but it's a lot better than using any migration tool (MM, Force.com IDE, Ant), simply because most of the dependencies are automatically calculated for you. Also, there's no shell scripts to run, no XML files to tweak, etc.

Of course, there are a few downsides. Notably, unmanaged packages can abort because of conflicts (e.g. identical field names on an object). There's also the upload delay, which means that after you click the upload button, it may take 30+ minutes before you can install it elsewhere. Finally, the installer will fail if there are any missing dependent packages or features, many of which you can build into an Ant script, meaning that for a bit of extra XML, you can actually fully automate the installation process.

Comment: I like unmanaged package approach but most of times before deployment there might be need to modify some code or some components and since its from PROD as the true copy we cannot modify code directly .So first time it will be worth to deploy in a developer org .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes, the OP is asking how they get their code and stuff into the developer org to begin with. An unmanaged package tends to be the easiest.

Answer (score 3):

The better solution is to simply use [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/).

You will need a package.xml which you can get using Mavensmate by the same process .Once you have a src file then you can run the deploy command to deploy .

Copy paste solution is tedious process and exploring ANT for this task will save you tons of time .

Trailhead has good [tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/alm_deployment/alm_migrate) to begin with .The process initially will involve some set up on your machine to install ANT and Java and other dependencies but once your local machine is set its simple tool to use and learn